# How to send unknows number of variables to controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have view with gmaps.js map displaying markers from database. I added filter by manufacturers. html:

```
<select id="filtrs-1">
                    <option value="all">All</option>
                    <option value="manufacturer1">Manufacturer1</option>
                    <option value="manufacturer2">Manufacturer2</option>
                    <option value="manufacturer3">Manufacturer3</option>
                    <option value="manufacturer4">Manufacturer4</option>
        </select><br />
<button id="go-button" type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

and jquery:

```
 var puzzles = <?= json_encode($puzzles);?>;
    var allMap;    
    $(document).ready(function(){
                var allMap = new GMaps({
                  el: '#map',
                  zoom: 7,
                  lat: 37.4419,
                  lng: -122.1419
                });
                loadJsonMap(allMap, puzzles);

                $('#go-button').click(function(){
                    var filtrs1 = $('#filtrs-1').val();
                    $.get('<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/map/filter/' + filtrs1, function(response){
                        allMap.removeMarkers();
                        loadJsonMap(allMap, response);
                    });
                });
            });
```

where `loadJsonMap` loads markers on map. So when I click on button I ger ajax call for filter method:

```
public function filter($man)
        {
                if ($man == 'all'){
                    $data = $this->puzzles_model->get_puzzleCoordinates();
                }else{
                    $data = $this->puzzles_model->get_puzzlesByManufacturer($man);
                }               
                header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
                header('Content-Type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

and map if filtered by manufacturer! I am beginner at jquery so I fell realy proud of myself. However I am stuck at next step. User should be able to filter by more than one manufacturer, so I changed html:

```
<button id="go-button" type="button">Click Me!</button>

    <div class="multiselect">
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value="all" />All</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value="manufacturer1" />manufacturer1</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value="manufacturer2" />manufacturer2</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value="manufacturer3" />manufacturer3</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox"  value="manufacturer4" />manufacturer4</label>
    </div>
```

but can not get ant further...

1. How should I collect data from checkbox? Should I have seperate id for every value?
2. How should I change my filter method so It could get array of values (problem is that I do not know how many checkboxes will be checked)?

Comment: You should use array in checkbox names. Ex: manufacturer[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one you need to set checkbox as array like name="xyz[]".
See below code you can fetch multiple select checkbox value as array and comma separated string.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#go-button").on("click",function(){
  
    var chb = $("input[name='go[]']:checked");
    var multi_val = [];
    $.each(chb,function(){
      multi_val.push($(this).val());
    });
    console.log(multi_val);
    console.log(multi_val.join());
    
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go-button" type="button">Click Me!</button>

<div class="multiselect">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="go[]" value="all" />All</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="go[]" value="manufacturer1" />manufacturer1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="go[]" value="manufacturer2" />manufacturer2</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="go[]"  value="manufacturer3" />manufacturer3</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="go[]" value="manufacturer4" />manufacturer4</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the values from the dropdown menu you will have to use .val() in jQuery. Below is a piece of code which retrieves the value and alerts it.

```
$('#go-button').click(function() {
  var manufacturer = $('select#filtrs-1').val();
  alert(manufacturer);
});
```

I use the `.click()` event on the button to start looking for the value in the dropdown. We can simply refer to your select element with `select#filtrs-1` we set the var with `var manufacturer =` the actual `.val()` will retrieve the value from your element. With a simple alert we can check if the value is actually retrieved after the code has run.

JSfiddle below

https://jsfiddle.net/gv2rkyn3/2/

Comment: Completely failed to understand what you wanted so I rewrote a jQuery version here hope it helps!

Comment: No you got it right first time! I have no problems with select tag. I am able to get value of filtrs-1 and call another method that updates the map. I do not undestand how to get multiple values. Now user can filter map only by one manufacturer or see all, but I want to implement possibility to filter manufacturer1 AND manufacturer2. If both options checked, how do I get both values and how do I pass both values to method?